# Can't keep width of div in tailwindcss framework

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a copy of the example TailwindCSS card element, but instead of the default style (the bottom one in the below example) I want to make the area where the picture is another text area.

However, I can't get the (former-)picture `div` to keep its width / dimensions the way it does when there is a picture in it. Currently, the two `div`s inside the topmost card seem to overlap.

What am I missing? How can I make the (former-)picture `div` maintain width as windows resize etc as it does in the original when there is a picture in it?

```
      <div>

        <div class="max-w-md mx-auto bg-indigo-100 rounded-xl m-5 shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl">
          <div class="bg-black-100 w-1/2 ">
            <p class="bg-black-100">Testing text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="w-1/2">
            <div class="p-8">
              <div class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-semibold">WELCOME</div>
              <a href="#" class="block mt-1 text-lg leading-tight font-medium text-black hover:underline">Rec</a>
              <p class="mt-2 text-gray-500">Testing text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>

        <div class="max-w-md mx-auto bg-white rounded-xl m-5 shadow-md overflow-hidden md:max-w-2xl">
          
          <div class="md:flex">
            <div class="md:flex-shrink-0">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover md:h-full md:w-48" src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/img/photo-test.png`} alt="Man looking at item at a store" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-8">
              <div class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm text-indigo-500 font-semibold">2021 - Present · STUFF</div>
              <a href="#" class="block mt-1 text-lg leading-tight font-medium text-black hover:underline">STUFF</a>
              <p class="mt-2 text-gray-500">Testing text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It has to do with how `<div>` elements act in a default manner. If a div isn't given a specific width or height, it will default to `auto` as its initial height and width values. What that means is that it will try as hard as possible to keep an element the same width as its parent container. This is in contrast to any additional space being created from margins, padding, or borders as well.

Comment: @Martin thats what I figured, but I have tried editing the width parameters in `<div class="bg-black-100 w-1/2 ">` and nothing seems to change how wide it gets.